# Update MySite Thumbnail Photo in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, userprofiles

I was able to do this in SharePoint 2013, however the code below does not work in SharePoint 2016 (on-Prem) and no error is thrown. Anyone else encounter this?

**the PowerShell code:**

```
# SharePoint 2010/2013/2016
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$mySitesUrl = Read-Host `n`n"Enter the Url of the MySites Web Application[http://mysites.portal.contoso.com]"`n

# Update MySite Thumbnail Photo Store
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation $mySitesUrl

Write-Host "MySite Thumbnail Update Completed!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: Works fine here. Did you give the user running it full control in Administrators as well as Permissions on the UPSA?

Comment: yes, I have all the correct permissions.  I can manually upload a picture to a MySite just fine.  Using Softerra's LDAP Browser I can see the Photo however I noticed that when the LDAP browser displays the page, the photo pops up real big before the LDAP program changes the height/width for display.  So another question.  If the photo being uploaded is large, will that affect SharePoint's ability to import it ?

Comment: No, it won't. How are you otherwise getting the pictures into the UPSA? MIM is required here as AD Import does not bring in thumbnailPhoto.

Comment: The Photos are already in AD.  Are you saying that I need Microsoft Identity Manager in order for SharePoint 2016's  (on-Prem) UserProfile Sync to Import the "ThumbnailPhoto" mapping?

Comment: That is correct. Or custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Identity Manager 2016 is needed to import the profile photos.

For the script to run correctly you must run it under the *`SP Farm`* account. This is very import for it to work.